Finding a convex function whose subdifferential is a hypercube
This is a HW problem for a class in convex optimization:

Find a convex $f:\mathbb R^n \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ such that $\partial f(0)=[1,2]^n$.

Here $\overline{\mathbb R}$ denotes the extended reals, $\partial f(\cdot)$ denotes the subdifferential of $f$, and $[1,2]^n$ is an $n$-dimensional hypercube.
What I tried: I know that $\partial \lVert \cdot \rVert_1(0)$ is just the closed unit ball of the dual norm to $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$, which is the hypercube $[-1,1]^n$. Then this hypercube is related to $[1,2]^n$ by an affine transformation. So my main idea is to somehow use the chain rule for subdifferentials to modify the subdifferential of $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ at $0$ to get the right hypercube. But I haven't been able to get it to work out correctly.
Also, I can solve this problem in the $n=1$ case. One solution is given by the piecewise function $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 2x, x \geq 0 \\ x, x \leq 0 \end{cases}.$$ Then $\partial f(0)$ consists of slopes of lines that lie below the graph of $f$, i.e., $\partial f(0)=[1,2]$. But I can't see yet how to generalize this.
Question: Is this approach of using the chain rule for subdifferentials correct (if so, how do I find the right matrix?) I think a hint would be enough to allow me to solve this problem.

One approach would be to compare your "almost solution" $|\cdot|_1$ in dimension $n = 1$ with your solution $f$. Then you could try to generalize your $f$ to multiple dimensions.
